# Im getting an error if theres no active locations in react google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, next.js, react-google-maps

I have a code thats will automatically put a marker and route destination if theres a data in the array. But if the array is null its gets an error. How to run a map even if theres no data in my array.

This is my sample code.

googlemap.js

```js
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import {
      withGoogleMap,
      GoogleMap,
      withScriptjs,
      Marker,
      DirectionsRenderer
    } from "react-google-maps";
    import "./config";
    
    function MapDirectionsRenderer(props) {
    
      const [directions, setDirections] = useState(null);
      const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        
        const { places, travelMode } = props;
    
        const waypoints = places.map(p => ({
          location: { lat: p.latitude, lng: p.longitude },
          stopover: true
        }));
        const origin = waypoints.shift().location;
        const destination = waypoints.pop().location;
    
        const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsService.route(
          {
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: travelMode,
            waypoints: waypoints
          },
          (result, status) => {
            console.log(result)
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              setDirections(result);
            } else {
              setError(result);
            }
          }
        );
      });
    
      if (error) {
        return <h1>{error}</h1>;
      }
      return (
        directions && (
          <DirectionsRenderer directions={directions} />
        )
      );
    }
    
    const Map = withScriptjs(
      withGoogleMap(props => (
        <GoogleMap
          defaultCenter={props.defaultCenter}
          defaultZoom={props.defaultZoom}
        >
          {props.markers.map((marker, index) => {
            const position = { lat: marker.latitude, lng: marker.longitude };
            return <Marker key={index} position={position} />;
          })}
          <MapDirectionsRenderer
            places={props.markers}
            travelMode={google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING}
          />
        </GoogleMap>
      ))
    );
    
    export default Map;
```

Map.js

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import Map from './googlemap';
    import "./config";
    
    
    const googleMapsApiKey = "myapikey";
    
    const places = coordinate;
    
    const App = props => {
      
      const {
        loadingElement,
        containerElement,
        mapElement,
        defaultCenter,
        defaultZoom
      } = props;
    
      return (
        
        <Map
          googleMapURL={
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' +
            googleMapsApiKey +
            '&libraries=geometry,drawing,places'
          }
          markers={places}
          loadingElement={loadingElement || <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
          containerElement={containerElement || <div style={{height: "80vh"}}/>}
          mapElement={mapElement || <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
          
          defaultZoom={defaultZoom || 11}
        />
      );
    };
    
    
    export default App;
    
    
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import Map from './googlemap';
    import "./config";
    
    
    const googleMapsApiKey = "myapikey";
    
    const places = coordinate;
    
    const App = props => {
      
      const {
        loadingElement,
        containerElement,
        mapElement,
        defaultCenter,
        defaultZoom
      } = props;
    
      return (
        
        <Map
          googleMapURL={
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' +
            googleMapsApiKey +
            '&libraries=geometry,drawing,places'
          }
          markers={places}
          loadingElement={loadingElement || <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
          containerElement={containerElement || <div style={{height: "80vh"}}/>}
          mapElement={mapElement || <div style={{height: `100%`}}/>}
          
          defaultZoom={defaultZoom || 11}
        />
      );
    };
    
    
    export default App;
```

Btw the map will work if there a two routes available if theres 1 or none the map will not show.

Comment: Can you add an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) in your question? You can use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/). I also removed the API key in your question. Please don't share your API key in public sites in the future.

Comment: Hi! @Pagemag can i give you a link to my repo of the sample project because it mas made in Next js.